# How do I pick up my car I customized in gta 5

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I customized a car in the ifruit app and later received a txt in the game saying to go to a customs to fulfill the order but whichever one I go to I can't seem to figure out how to fulfill it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bring your personal vehicle to a LS Customs. From there you can choose the upgrades you bought from the iFruit app.